# How to separate and add values in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

df1:

```
 A  |  B  |  C
----|-----|----
 2T |  3K | 0.0None
 3K |  7K |  4T
0.0N|  4T |  3T
```

What I would need is to segregate and add values that have T and K in them and return only number without text. Also to completely ignore 0.0Nonne.

Final table should look like:

df2:

```
 T  |  K
----|----
 2  |  3
 4  |  10
 7  |  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stack` the dataframe to reshape then use `Series.str.extract` with regex pattern having named capturing groups and `sum` on `level=0`:

```
p = r'^(?:(?P<T>[\d.]+(?=T))|(?P<K>[\d.]+(?=K)))'
s = df.stack().str.extract(p).astype(float).sum(level=0)
```

---

```
     T     K
0  2.0   3.0
1  4.0  10.0
2  7.0   0.0
```

Comment: @bassline_ballerina Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi, it is working, but it is not giving me right results. Real dataframe that I have has values:  


First row:  110.0T   141.9T    85.0T    0.0None
Seconde row:  125.0T   109.65T  75.0T    120.69999999999999T
````
your code returns:

First row   9 for T and 0 for K
Second row    7e+13 for T and 0 for K

Comment: It seems to me that it is only taking in to calculation number after dot.

Comment: @bassline_ballerina Can you try `s = df.stack().str.extract(r'^(?:(?P<T>[\d.]+(?=T))|(?P<K>[\d.]+(?=K)))').astype(float).sum(level=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try extracting the values with `str.extract`. Then `groupby().sum()`:

```
(df.stack().str.extract('^(\d+)(T|K)')
   .dropna()
   .assign(order=lambda x: x.groupby([1]).cumcount())
   .pivot(index='order',columns=[1], values=0)
   .astype(float)
   .groupby('T', as_index=False).sum()
)
```

Output:

```
1    T     K
0  2.0   3.0
1  3.0   0.0
2  4.0  10.0
```